# Octave - Solve equation and create Matrix with values

Tags: matrix, octave

Good morning...

**I need to write in Octave a function y = interval(a). The function needs to create an matrix y of dimension n x 2. Each line must contain ymin and ymax multiplied by pi/2.**

The interval in x is:

```
x = 0:.1:25;
```

The equation to output the matrix must be:

```
cos(x) = exp(a*x)-1
```

The value of a will be given in the argument of the function -> interval(4)

So far is all i've done. This thing is confusing me a lot because i'm trying to make octave calculate cos(x) = exp(a*x)-1 and then create the matrix n x 2 with ymin and ymax in every line multiplied by pi/2 and cannot do it.

Here is my atempt:

```
function [y] = interval(a)
y = 0:.1:25;
h = @(y) cos(y);
g = @(y) exp(a*y)-1;
c = pi/2;
y = [h(y),g(y)];
interval = [y'];
end
```

**Any solutions...**

EDIT -> new code after the comment sugestion by Nick J:

```
function [X] = intervalos(a)

% limpar a memoria de todas as vars e funções
clear functions;

% limpa consola
clc;

% intervalo para x
x = 0:.1:25;
% ambas as funções h(x) e g(x)
h = @(x) cos(x);
g = @(x) exp(a*x)-1;
% multiplicador
c = pi/2;
% saída
xh = [h(x)*c];
xg = [g(x)*c];
fprintf('Matrix X:\n');
X = [xh', xg'];

% limpar a memoria de todas as vars e funções
clear functions;

endfunction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you've misunderstood how to return values to a function. The last line in your function, `interval = [y'];` serves no purpose. The function will return the last value you assign to `y`. `interval` is just the name you call the function with it is not a variable within the function.

Also, you want to pay attention to the orientation of your  `y`  vectors and the outputs of `h` & `g`. At the moment, `y` is created as a row vector. When you then do `y = [h, g]` it will create a really long row vector, with the values of `h` followed by the values of `g`. Instead, you should make `h` and `g` as column vectors either before putting them into `y`, or within the assignment to y (with something like `y = [h(y)',g(y)']`).

All that said, it's still not completely clear to me if what you are doing will produce the output you say you want from that equation with `x`.  Perhaps you can provide a very simple example of what you think the output should look like for a small input.  Or more simply stated, what you've written will run in Matlab/Octave, but I can't tell what mathematical output you're looking for in the first place.

Also, I don't think there's any real need for the `clear functions` statement within the function.  Any of those functions are created local to the `interval` function, and no longer exist after the function runs.

Edit:  ok, looks like you've fixed the return value, so now the last definition for `X` will be returned by the function, and this that it will be a n x 2 matrix.

Edit: it's also more clear now what you're trying to get as an output. You are trying to produce a matrix with values of the left and right hand sides of that equation for `x`.  This was not clear before how `y` in any way came out of that equation which had no `y` in it. It might be more clear to say specifically that you are looking to produce the matrix 
`[cos(x)*pi/2,exp(a*x-1)*pi/2]` 
as the equation you wrote above doesn't come into the process at all.

at that point, you function could simply be:

```
function output_matrix = interval(a)
  x = [1:.1:25]';
  output_matrix = [cos(x),(exp(a*x)-1)]*pi/2;
endfunction
```

Comment: I'm trying to find a way in octave docs and others to convert h and g to a single row each with many lines. The only way i figure was through fprintf but i need a matrix not fprintf. I think you gave me a clue to what i need to do. I will make the changes and then edit the question for you to see. Thanks.

Comment: Edit done. I think the creation of the matrix is correct. Now i need to call that matrix values in another m.file inside another function. Do you know the way?

Comment: I was on mobile and couldn't add much detail to my response. let me add a bit more explanation there and see if that clears things up.

Comment: you call your function the same way you call any function like `sin` or `cos`.  When Octave sees that you're calling a function, it first looks to see if there is a function defined in memory with that name, then it looks in the local folder, then it starts looking through it's normal paths for functions. So if you've saved `interval.m` in the same folder as the other m.file, it will use your function when it sees a line like:
`DATA = interval(somenumber)`